# trying to identify these bracket for removal for single post, kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to remove a kitchen faucet, and I can't figure out how to remove the faucet with these weird 'elephant ear' brackets. Can anyone identify them or provide a suggestion on how to remove? Thank you!

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7KYJ.jpg
[image]

[image]

Comment: Care to tell us what brand (and even better) what model of faucet this is?

Comment: Can you provide a photo from the top? Wondering if this faucet was glued in place.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was a Costco faucet, and once I realized that the hex screw was covered up by mineral deposits, I cleaned it off and I was able to use the link below to get it off easily.

[image]

[image]

<sup>Both images from [TerryLove.com](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/costco-waterridge-906242-kitchen-faucet-pictures.75262/)</sup>

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. Please give yourself a check mark for your answer as soon as the system will let you. Also note that I embedded the key images from the link you provided. Embedding images/key descriptive text (with appropriate source attribution) is expected here because links can die in an internet-instant, which would render your answer useless in the future.

Answer (score 1):

these 'elephant ear' brackets are fixation kits, the function is just like a washer. firstly you need to remove the silicon glue, and then use a suitable spanner to unscrew it , then you can remove the brackets.

Comment: Generally, I'd agree with you, but I don't see anything to attach a suitable spanner to. Care to download a copy of the OP's picture and draw an arrow or two on it showing where the OP should use the spanner, then [edit] it into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to sort out access from above (partial faucet disassembly, presumably) to turn the screws.